# Android ImageView with Picasso show white src only in 5.1.1

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I showed a GridView dialog with ImageView to choose for profile picture. I took pictures from local storage. I used Picasso Library to show Images.

My problem is that ImageViews show only white screen like this.

[image: Here is the result]

And it's only in version 5.1.1. Not in 4.x.x and 5.1.2.

I haven't yet tested in 5.x.x that is lower than 5.1.1.

Here is my codes to get Images url

```
private List<String> getListofImage() {


    List<String> imgList = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    // content:// style URI for the "primary" external storage volume
    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    // Make the query.
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // Selection arguments (none)
            null        // Ordering
    );

    Log.i("ListingImages", " query count=" + cur.getCount());

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

        int column_index = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        do {
            // Get the field values
            cur.getString(column_index);

            // Do something with the values.
            Log.i("ListingImages", " bucket=" + cur.getString(column_index)
                    + "  date_taken=" + "");
            imgList.add(cur.getString(column_index));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());

    }

    return imgList;
}
```

Here is the sample Image Url

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150807_191201.jpg
```

And this is the code from my adapter

```
if (mImageList.get(i).contains("/storage")) {

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mImageList.get(i)));

                Picasso.with(RegisterActivity.this)
                        .load(uri)
                        .resize(512, 512)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(vh.imageView);

        } else {

            Picasso.with(RegisterActivity.this)
                    .load(mImageList.get(i))
                    .into(vh.imageView);
        }
```

I search around but I don't see this issue. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: add log statement with uri.toString ....that will tell what exactly is the path of uri..as it seems if condition holds true and that is possible case where issue may be lying!

Comment: Hi uncertain-eer, this is the uri, "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150807_191201.jpg"

Comment: remove the single '/' from ur url.. and load it to picasso. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding prefix `file://` when you reference your image file via uri:

```
Picasso.with(RegisterActivity.this)
.load(new File("file://"+mImageList.get(i)))
.into(vh.imageView);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(RegisterActivity.this)
.load("file://"+mImageList.get(i))
.into(vh.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading from a file instead a uri like

```
Picasso.with(RegisterActivity.this)
    .load(new File(mImageList.get(i)))
    .resize(512, 512)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(vh.imageView);
```